# Opening up a timeout pop-up as a new window without pop-up blocker intervention in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I would appreciate if I can get some help here. I am opening up a new pop-up window once the session times out for a portal. Unfortunately, the pop-up blocker blocks it. Is there a way to capture the user's click event as a trusted event, store it for a desired amount of time and use it when I require the pop-up?

Comment: Don't use browser pop-ups to handle your authentication. Popup blockers will break your auth. Use modals instead.

Comment: @BenM Hi Ben, our initial solution was a beautiful modal dialog box but the client wants a new window (I know they are sticking to the legacy system style)! Though it is a session pop-up, the pop-up does nothing but controlling a timer scheduled from an Observable. It gets reset on every server request. Session cookies are handled by a different application altogether to which we redirect whenever required. The warning = pop is just for displaying the countdown from the last idle time. Once th user is logged out in the parent window, the child window closes.